# what is the purpose of multiplying Quaternion with Vector3

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

the result movement is so complicated, the circle motion is the most used one but the others for example when you're changing other axis of Quaternion like X and Z you gets results like a butterfly movement.
what is the others usages rather than having a circular motion?

Comment: Quaternions are a 6-dimensional representation compressed into 4 values, used to rotate 3D objects in a single operation (Euler takes 3 operations, one per axis).  Without a concrete example of what you're seeing vs what you're expecting, I can't help you much.

Comment: In short: It rotates a Vector. E.g. `transform.rotation * Vector3.forward` basically returns the same vector as `transform.forward` the local Z axis which is rotated according to the objects global rotation